# История цен. Как правильно? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Как правильно спроектировать таблицы, чтобы учитывать изменение цен на услуги. Есть две таблицы:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM services;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| service_id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_id     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_end   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service_start | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM lessons;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lesson_id    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_name  | varchar(60)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| lesson_worth | decimal(20,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Необходимо, чтобы в таблице `services` хранились цены до их изменения, если таковые и будут, то есть изменения цен для `lessons` не задевали имеющиеся строки в `services`.
Нашел решение с таблицей хранящая историю изменения цен (если есть лучше, предложите), то какую цену хранить в `services`: из таблицы истории или из `lessons`?

**UPD**:

Пришел к этой модели, исходя из ответа.

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM services;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| service_id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_id     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_end   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service_start | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM lessons;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lesson_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_name | varchar(60) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM worths;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| worth_id   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lesson_id  | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| worth      | decimal(20,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| worth_date | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Для начала неплохо было бы описать бизнес логику. Что такое services и что такое lessons, как их цены связаны между собой?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, `services` - конечная услуга, хранящая занятие, его начало, и его конец. `lessons` - занятия, название и цена.

Comment: присоединяюсь к комментарию выше. Непонятно, для чего это и что в итоге должно получиться.

Comment: К вариант можно в одной таблице сделать. У каждой строчки сделать дату начала действия и дату окончания, при обновлении записи обновлять старую запись проставляя ей дату окончания действия и вставлять новую с текущей датой начала действия .

Comment: Опиши, пожалуйста: при покупке урока, он может продлеваться помесячно? Если да, то один месяц будет стоить n (и цена к нему должна стоять n на протяжении этого месяца), а следующий месяц уже должен стоить m? В чем суть этого?

Comment: @Alexxosipov, при покупке он не продлевается по завершению `service_end`, дальше будет использоваться новая запись с `lesson_id` и новыми датами `service_start, service_end`

Comment: Почему тогда не писать цену на момент покупки в таблицу service? Либо я что-то не понимаю, либо все просто

Comment: @Alexxosipov в моем понимании *почему не писать цену на момент покупки в таблицу `service`* - чтобы избежать ошибку ввода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нашел решение с таблицей хранящая историю изменения цен (если есть лучше, предложите)

По моей практике, таблица с историей изменения - это лучшее решение.

> какую цену хранить в services: из таблицы истории или из lessons?

С точки зрения реляционной алгебры, если что-то можно получить из одних таблиц, то не стоит это добавлять в другие. Т.е. в идеале цена должна храниться только в таблице истории цен.

С точки зрения производительности, имеет смысл ту цену, которая читается чаще других (например, актуальную на сегодня, или цену на дату открытия услуги) хранить в основной таблице. Но делать это имеет смысл только если вы уверены, что этот один join с таблицей истории серьезно сказывается на производительности.

Поправка. Если для клиента может предоставляться индивидуальная скидка, то поле с ценой в services обязательно.

Comment: Насчет поправки: то есть поля `скидка` и `конечная стоимость`, которая рассчитывается исходя из арифметики полей `скидка` и `цена`?

Comment: @Pakhan, зависит от бизнес-логики. В случае, если переговоры ведутся индивидуально с каждым клиентом, то итоговая цена может быть вообще никак не связана с ценой по прейскуранту. В этом случае подходит только поле `цена` в таблице `services`. Если скидка выбирается менеджером/продавцом из фиксированного набора, то скидки записать в отдельную таблицу, а в `services` записывать `id` скидки и рассчитанную цену, округленную до копеек. Это нужно для того, чтобы сумма, полученная одним запросом не разошлась с суммой по всем строкам, посчитанной бухгалтером.